# Change object type to another that inherits from the same class type with keeping root properties set

Tags: c#, entity-framework, type-conversion, entity-framework-5

I have two classes as follows :

```
class Article
{
 public int Id {get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
}

class DetailedArticle : Article 
{
  public string SerialNumber {get;set;}
}
```

I did create an article like :

```
var article = new Article {Id=1, Name="ItemName"}
```

Now, I would like to change article object type from `Article` to `DetailedArticle` with keeping properties as they are (Id = 1 and Name="ItemName").
Knowing that I am using `EF5` 
Is this possible ? How ? Will EF5 detect type changes ?
Any alternatives in case not possible ?

Comment: You couldn't *change* an `Article` to a `DetailedArticle`. You could create another `DetailedArticle` object that has the same properties as the `Article`.

Comment: I know that straightforward type conversion cannot be done. C# is not a dynamic language. though trying to find some implicit conversions or any workaround that some c# experts found to this particular problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose the straightforward way:

```
var article = context.Articles.Find(1);
context.Articles.Remove(article);
var detailedArticle = new DetailedArticle
{
    Id = article.Id,
    Name = article.Name,
    SerialNumber = "ABC"
};
context.Articles.Add(detailedArticle);
context.SaveChanges();
```

It won't work if `Id` is an autogenerated identity (you'll get a new Id value) or if you have other entities refering to the `article` with a FK constraint (you can't delete the `article` then).

I believe your only workaround then will be using SQL directly:

- For TPH inheritance:

  ```
  context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
      @"UPDATE Articles SET SerialNumber = N'xyz',
                            Discriminator = N'DetailedArticle' WHERE Id = 1");
  ```
- For TPT inheritance:

  ```
  context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
      @"INSERT INTO DetailedArticles VALUES (1, N'xyz')");
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on already great answer...

> Types are highly 'rooted' into the code-first, how it stores, queries
>   and materializes objects.

The least `identity` you get when using the `TPH` - as **those records practically differ only 'by one field' value in the Db** (they're using same table). Still 'up in C#' you can't do much to just 'rewire'.

So, if you sense you're going to need that (providing you're not already in production) best is to set inheritance as TPH (like you have now already, if that's the whole thing) - and just do direct `SQL` to  'adjust' that field. No matter how dirty that may look, it still the easiest of all solutions.

Next would be - loading the old one - remembering all its associations, related records - removing it - adding new again - which may not be fun either.